# Best way to make progress with textblock

Tags: c#, xaml

I'm trying to make a textblock with xaml binding. The text should appear according to the number of files processed. Like: 1/845 or 845/845 and some text that would be added.

I already wasted days trying to do this, but the text does not appear or only the end 845 appears. There is no count in the UI.

Could someone help me out and indicate a way to do a simple text progress count. I don't need a progressive bar with animation. I just want a file count as you do with a file copy.

Xaml code from MainWindow binding my class on core project.

**Xaml code**

```
<materialDesign:Card x:Name="Card" Padding="32" Margin="16" Height="81" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
            <!--<materialDesign:Card.Resources>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type formater:FfxTextEncoder}" ItemsSource="{Binding Data, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </materialDesign:Card.Resources>-->
            <materialDesign:Card.DataContext>
                <formater:FfxTextEncoder/>
            </materialDesign:Card.DataContext>
            <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlock" Style="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignTitleTextBlock}"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       DataContext="{Binding ActiveEntity}"
                       Text="{Binding Data, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
            </TextBlock>
        </materialDesign:Card>
```

**Command delegate**

```
private void OnInsertTxtEvent(FileSystemObjectInfo fsoInfo)
            {
                _ = fsoInfo.FileSystemInfo switch
                {
                    DirectoryInfo => TextDirectoryEncoder(fsoInfo.FileSystemInfo),
                    FileInfo => TextFileEncoder(fsoInfo.FileSystemInfo),
                    _ => throw new InvalidOperationException(@"Tipo desconhecido!!!")
                };
            }
```

**Directory to process**

```
private async Task TextDirectoryEncoder(FileSystemInfo fsoInfo)
        {
            if (fsoInfo is not DirectoryInfo info) return;

            try
            {
                var dirs = Util.LocalDir(info.FullName);
                var encoder = new FfxTextEncoder(dirs);
                var s = new SplashScreenWindow();
                encoder._threads.Add(encoder.GetThreadId() + " in " + nameof(TextDirectoryEncoder));
                s.Show();
                _data = encoder.Data;

                await encoder.EncodeTextAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

                _ = MessageBox.Show(encoder.Data ?? "Maybe all files is translated or text file is missing!");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                _ = SimpleLog.Log(e.Message, SimpleLog.Severity.Exception);
                throw;
            }
            
        }
```

**code behind**

```
public async Task EncodeTextAsync()
        {
            _threads.Add(GetThreadId() + " in method " + nameof(EncodeTextAsync));

            await _dirs.Files/*.Where(x => !x.FileTranslated.Exists)*/.ParallelForEachAsync( item =>
                {
                    _threads.Add(GetThreadId() + " in method inside " + nameof(EncodeTextAsync));

                    ++cc;
                    _ = item.Extension switch
                    {
                        FileExtension.DialogsText or FileExtension.TutorialText => EncodeText(item),
                        FileExtension.LocationNamePack => Task.Run(() => new DcpPackFile().Initialize(item).Validate().TextInsert().JoinDcp()),
                        _ => throw new InvalidOperationException("Haven't I implemented this yet?")
                    };
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                },
                MaxDop
            ).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }

private async Task EncodeText(IFile item)
        {
            _threads.Add(GetThreadId() + " in task " + nameof(EncodeText));

            if (item.FileText.Length is not 0)
            {
                var counter = ++_counter;
                Data = $"Congratulations, {counter} files converted!";
                _threads.Add(Data);

                _ = Directory.CreateDirectory(
                    item.FileTranslated.DirectoryName ?? throw new InvalidOperationException());
                await
                    $@"{item.Application} -i -t {Applications.Table} {item.FileBin} {item.FileText.FullName} {item.FileTranslated.FullName}"
                        .ExecuteTask().ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
        }
```

I used a debug log to check the threads.

```
_threads.Add(GetThreadId() + " in method inside " + nameof(EncodeTextAsync));
```

[Threads_log](https://www104.zippyshare.com/v/g57Z6JkK/file.html%5DThreads_log.zip)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can use a `Label` control with a `IMultiValueConverter` converter which are then bound to two `int` notified properties. The converter takes in the ints to achieve and report the changeable numbers in the format of "12/200".

### VM

```
private int _PartA;
private int _PartB;

public int PartA
{
    get => _PartA;
    set { _PartA = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(PartA)); }
}


public int PartB
{
    get => _PartB;
    set { _PartB = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(PartB)); }
}
```

### Xaml

Create a label to hold the value, or another control of your choosing.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:ConvertToProgress x:Key="MultiConvert"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Label>
    <Label.Content>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MultiConvert}">
            <Binding Path="PartA" />
            <Binding Path="PartB" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </Label.Content>
</Label>
```

### Converter

Then have the converter convert to a string as desired:

```
public class ConvertToProgress : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) 
        => $"{(int)values[0]}/{(int) values[1]}";

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) 
        => throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```